# Windows Management Instrumentation - How to get Server Roles and connected Services/Drives

Tags: powershell, python, windows-server, wmi, windows-server-2019

For a work project I'm tasked with developing a python script that reads the roles from a a Windows-Failover Cluster running in Windows Server 2019 Standard Eval. If I need to provide more info, I can do that

The Problem:

I can't find the WMI-Classes/Objects to get the needed Information, spefically the roles and the drives. This Information is viewable in the Windows-Failover-Cluster Manager on Windows Server.

What i tried:

I already can collect information about Cluster Disks and common Information about the Cluster. I tried to Google how to get Role information with no success. I hope someone here can help.
Here is a example from my working Python Code:

```
import wmi
wmi_MSCluster = wmi.WMI(namespace="MSCluster")
class MSCluster_Cluster(object):
def __init__(self, name, description, preferredsite, fqdn, caption, quorumpath, roles, sharedvolumesroot, status):
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
    self.preferredsite = preferredsite
    self.fqdn = fqdn
    self.caption = caption
    self.quorumpath = quorumpath
    self.roles = roles
    self.sharedvolumesroot = sharedvolumesroot
    self.status = status

wmi_mscluster = wmi.WMI(moniker='//./root/MSCluster:MSCluster_Cluster')
for MScluster in wmi_mscluster():
    ClusterObject: MSCluster_Cluster = MSCluster_Cluster(MScluster.Name, MScluster.Description,
                                                             MScluster.PreferredSite, MScluster.Fqdn, MScluster.Caption,
                                                             MScluster.QuorumPath, MScluster.Roles,
                                                             MScluster.SharedVolumesRoot, MScluster.Status)
```

Where in WMI do I get the information about Server Roles and connected Services/Drives to that Role. I'm unable to find the right place to look .

Comment: Why is this tagged PowerShell? You are not using any PowerShell code at all, it's all WMIC.exe level stuff, via python. Now, that's all well and good, but this also assume you know all you need since WMIC.exe has no IntelliSense or tab completion. PowerShell does as does just pulling this from .Net namespaces directly. So, you have to manually look that up. WFCM shows this because it's coded to do so, there is no special magic being used.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools that will show you object models. The Microsoft WMIExplorer.exe for example- 
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-announcing-wmi-explorer-2-0 
or 
https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wmie

There are PowerShell versions of this.

You just need to know the namespace to ask. Example, If I was after server roles using VBScript, I'd just do something like this:

```
# cscript wmi-server-roles-and-features.vbs
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colRoleFeatures = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_ServerFeature")
For Each objRoleFeatures in colRoleFeatures
    wscript.echo objRoleFeatures.Name
Next
```

... I've been doing automation/scripting for years, but never with Python. So, I can't help you there.

Doing this in PowerShell is a direct thing because there are specific native cmdlets for it.

[Install or Uninstall Roles, Role Services, or Features](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-manager/install-or-uninstall-roles-role-services-or-features)

As well as stuff like...

```
Get-WmiObject -namespace "root\mscluster" ...
```

Or ...

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "select GroupComponent from mscluster_nodetoactivegroup" -namespace root\mscluster -computername ....
```